# How to send arbitrary download request to proper handler

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, network-programming

I'm building a Qt application and using the QNetworkAccessManager to manager my http requests. Due to the asyncronous nature of QNetworkAccessManager you have to bind a slot to recieve the QNetworkReply when it's done.

I'm new to multithreaded design so I'm not sure how to handle this. I will have 3 seperate types of network replies which need to be parsed in the bound slot and then passed to the correct handler. One will extract a link, the 2nd will extract a picture, and the third will parse a post request's reply to verify that it was successful. All of this takes place within a QWidget subclass.

So, I'm wondering how this is normally handled. As I see it, based purely on intuition as I've done little reading on this specific subject, I would think there are two ways to handle this. One would be to rebind the network manager's finished() signal depending on the call and the other would be to use some sort of state flags and check those to see what the reply is expected to be. What is the preferred method, not necessarily between these two, that's just all I could think of myself, someone more experienced may well have a better solution.

Now, I'm also fairly new to c++, so if the later is the better way what's the best way to handle flags in this case? Would I use a bitset, an enum/flag setting function, or something else? Thanks guys!

Comment: When you make a request do you know which type of reply will you get as a result of this request?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of reply you're going to get as a result of doing specific request you can connect [void QNetworkReply::finished ()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkreply.html#finished) signal to suitable handler.

Comment: Well the way I'm handling it is I created an enum to whole the different states, NO_REQUEST, INITIAL_REQUEST, IMAGE_REQUEST, POST_REQUEST and I connected a slot to QNetworkAccessManager::finished() which then goes through a switch statement and forwards the reply to the correct handler based on the enum state. Seems good to me, see any problems w/that method?

Comment: It's another solution, yes. If you switch on type you should really see [The Clean Code Talks -- Inheritance, Polymorphism, & Testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc). Using QNetworkReply::finished() seems to be cleaner solution if you know and have access to handlers in the moment you make requests. If you didn't know or didn't have access to handlers until after you received reply you would be forced to use your solution as mine wouldn't work in such a situation.

Comment: I could do it both ways, I guess I just thought the way you suggested was for w/e reason worse than the way I did it, but I guess it's the opposite. Thanks for the link, I'll check it out.